# mudança automática de style

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, css-transições

Estou usando o tema [Elevate](https://www.styleshout.com/demo/?theme=elevate) em meu site e desejo fazer uma alteração:

Atualmente a logo no canto superior esquerdo é exibida normalmente, porém ao descer pelo site, o estilo da mesma é alterado de 'display: block' para 'display: none'. Desejo que isso não ocorra, que mesmo navegando para baixo que a logo continue sendo exibida, porém até o momento, mesmo inspecionando o elemento não encontrei onde eu possa fazer essa alteração para que essa alteração de propriedade não ocorra.

Comment: Poderia passa o código? Seria melhor pra responde tu.

Comment: Passei o link do tema justamente por isso, porque não sei em que parte do código esta alteração ocorre. Daí como pelo link é possível ver a demonstração online do tema alguém mais experiente que eu pudesse encontrar inspecionando o código.

Comment: Eu sou programador mobile... Como vou ver código,se uso navegador mobile. Mas obrigado pela sua resposta a minha pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe se me fiz parecer mal educado, não era esta a intenção. Toda ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 1):

Com um pouco mais de 'investigação' consegui descobrir uma função no arquivo main.js que ocultava a logo, bastou comentá-la para resolver o problema.

```
   $(window).on('scroll', function() {

        var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
            siteHeader = $('header'),
            siteLogo = siteHeader.find('.logo'),
            triggerHeight = siteHeader.innerHeight();       

       if (y > triggerHeight) {
          siteLogo.fadeOut();        
       }
      else {
         siteLogo.fadeIn();
      }

    });
```

Peço novamente desculpas ao @maury-developer se causei uma má impressão em minha resposta.

Comment: `$(window).on('scroll', function() {

        var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
            siteHeader = $('header'),
            siteLogo = siteHeader.find('.logo'),
            triggerHeight = siteHeader.innerHeight();       

       if (y > triggerHeight) {
          siteLogo.fadeOut(); 
       }
      else {
         siteLogo.fadeIn();
      }

    });` Isso é um jQuery . Lendo esse código,você ver a equalizer sai quando desce a pagina. Leia : https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ a opacity fica 0 na pagina deve esse código que faz sumir.

Comment: Leia também: https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ FadeIn e FadeOut são animações do jQuery.